# How to cite in an appendix (and where to put the Citation list) of a PhD thesis?

Tags: phd, citations, writing, thesis

I have a table of studies and formula per study in the appendix, so sth like

```
study A     E = mc²
study B     v = ma
```

etc. For each study I need to cite a source. Now normally the citation list for the main part of document appears before the appendix. How do I handle this? Do I create a new citation list after the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a PhD thesis (as indicated in the tags of your question), check your university's reference style guide. I suspect, however, that it doesn't go into that much detail. So: 
**do what you like best**, as long as it's **clear** and **coherent**.

If you have many citations in the appendix, and you suspect that people will want to read the appendix and main document separately, just maintain two separate lists of citations. It makes each of them shorter, and thus easier to read.

If you have very few citations in the appendix, you can also consider citing them in a different style, such as footnotes. It keeps them separated from the main references, for clarity, but doesn't necessitate to have a full “appendix list of references” if it's very short.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the university isn't too clear about that.  I'll go with a second citation list then.

Comment: +1 for suggesting footnotes. Those are a good idea in an appendix, especially if there's just a citation or two. No need to bother with a whole second ref list.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on where your appendix falls in your document (or whether it will appear in the document at all). If appendix precedes references, just include citations in the regular reference list. If it follows, have a separate set of appendix-specific references. If it is separate, do the same as the latter case (a separate reference list).

This will depend on your style manual and publication outlet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The appendix will appear after the reference list. I'll go with a second citation list then.